# Is the Westend deployment process same as Rococo?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, rococo, substrate-parachain-template, westend

Rococo is testnet for Kusama and Westend is testnet for Polkadot. To prepare parachain for Kusama, we have to test our application on Rococo. Likewise, we should test our parachain on Westend before going to Polkadot.

For Rococo, there are some instructions provided here https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/acquire-a-testnet-slot/#request-a-parachain-slot.

We have to book Rococo slot request here https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Rococo&template=rococo.yaml

But I couldn't find specific instructions for Westend.

Is the Westend deployment process same as Rococo? Where should I give slot request for Westend? or Testing on Rococo is good enough to go for Polkadot?

Can somebody please help me to know the process for Westend deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rococo is a testnet built for testing parachains. Initially conceived to test parachain functionality back in summer 2020, it has now evolved to become the testnet for teams building parachains in the ecosystem.

Take a look at this great answer from Santiago about the difference between Rococo and Westend: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2759/2762

And a couple of interesting resources about testing parachains and Rococo:

- [Launch Parachains Guide](https://polkadot.network/launch-parachains/)
- Polkadot wiki: [Testing a parachain](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-pdk#testing-a-parachain)
- [Rococo Revamp – Becoming a Community Parachain Testbed](https://polkadot.network/blog/rococo-revamp-becoming-a-community-parachain-testbed/)

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I have one more question. If the parachain is not live on Polkadot and we want a long-lasting slot, should we reserve a ParaId on polkadot and use same for Rococo? Would this be enough to reserve a long-lasting slot on Rococo?

Comment: The permanent slots are typically assigned to teams who have completed a successful slot lease auction and have deployed a parachain with a slot on Polkadot. But mention it when you book the slot request in https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Rococo&template=rococo.yaml